# Unable to connect wear device to Nexus 5 ( 4.4.2)

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I have 2 devices running Android 4.4.2 (Nexus 5 and Galaxy Note 3) and both of them can't connect to android wear.

I'm able to pair devices with usual bluetooth - without this Android Wear application can't even see my watch. But then android wear app tries to connect to watch with no luck.

Wear's stacktrace

```
/HostWithRpcCallback﹕ Failed to send RPC
com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.WearableException: sendRpcAsync failed: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 4000, resolution=null}
        at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.GoogleApiClientHelper.throwIfFailed(GoogleApiClientHelper.java:98)
        at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:81)
        at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:78)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.actions.WearableHostWithRpcCallback$SendRpcCallbackWithId.onSendRpc(WearableHostWithRpcCallback.java:292)
        at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:78)
        at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:75)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.deliverResultCallback(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)ode here
```

This problem is not reproduced with 4.4.3+ and 4.4.0- android devices.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Mind to share some come so we actually might see what's wrong in it?

Comment: share some code you mean? I'm not able to connect devices at all without any code written. Android wear app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app&hl=e
always shows "connecting - disconnected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> If you have one watch and multiple phones or tablets:
>
> You can’t pair one watch with multiple phones or tablets at the same
>   time. You can switch which phone or tablet your watch is paired with,
>   **but you need to reset your watch to factory settings first**. Then you can pair your watch to the new phone or tablet.

https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6058799?hl=en

In my case I have 6 Android phones which can connect watch without resetting wear and 2 phones mandatory require wear reset.